# Only install certain components of React Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to only install certain components of React Material UI. Especially the [AutComplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component?

Comment: Your build system should handle tree-shaking for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than "Installing", what you are looking for seems to be only adding the components you use to your final bundle when your app is built, otherwise known as Treeshaking.

There's a guide in the documentation about this that might help you out.

https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/